# Best way to preserve excess tallow long-term

Tags: storage-method, freezing, food-preservation, beef-tallow

I received a shipment of [eight 14oz bottles](https://twitter.com/carnivivre/status/1197272173557227520/photo/1) of grass-fed beef tallow. I will use one bottle right away. What is the best way to preserve the rest of the seven?

One idea is to put the 7 bottles in a freezer, and take one by one out as needed. Will this work?

[image: Bottles of tallow]

FWIW, from the [FatWorks FAQ](https://fatworksfoods.com/faq.html) I located this; not sure how reliable that information is.

> Tallow is naturally shelf stable for years.
>
> You can freeze your fat for an even longer shelf life, years in fact.

Answer (score 3):

You can freeze tallow.  Dehydration and the freeze-thaw cycle of home freezers are the enemies of long term storage.  You can't stop the freeze-thaw cycle, but if you minimize exposure to dehydration (freezer burn) by storing full containers, or even vacuum packing, you can keep them that way for quite a while.

You added a picture, which is helpful.  I might not freeze glass jars.  You could risk expansion and breakage.

Comment: I will never freeze bottles already opened. I'm not sure how I'd vacuum pack a bottle that is already closed firmly with the lid that manufacture put on it (however I'm sure it is not vacuum inside, as even though the container is full it is not full to the brim/lid).

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Vacuum packing would be useful to prevent contact of the food with the air in the freezer which leads to freezer burn. If you freeze food in sealed jars, this is already the case, thus no vacuum packing necessary. You could put the jars in Ziploc bags if you are worrierd about the jars breaking.